# Installing OpenCV with contrib by homebrew

Tags: c++, opencv, homebrew, macos-sierra

I installed opencv with contrib by homebrew through this command `brew install opencv3 --with-contrib`and setup `pgk_config_path` as below.

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

I confirmed `opencv.pc` exist at directory. But when compile c++ file, got below error.

`` Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found ``

I use mac OS Sierra. Please help me.

Comment: What version of Python you have installed in your MAC?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 and 3.5.2 is installed

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: [http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/). I think it is helpful for your case.

Comment: It didn't find `opencv` because you installed `opencv3` not `opencv`. What command/`Makefile`/`CMakeLists.txt` did you use to compile your code?

Comment: I'm trying @KelvinS tutorial now. When compile, I use command ` g++ -o hoge.out hoge.cpp \`pkg-config --cflags opencv\` \`pkg-config --libs opencv\` `

Comment: You installed `opencv3` not `opencv`. You need to use `pkg-config --cflags` and `pkg-config --libs` with the `opencv3` pkg-config file.

Comment: I had to copy /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc  to /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv3.pc 
 details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042674/1602316